# How to find out architecture on linux?

Tags: linux, odroid

I am using an odroid c2 and want to install `libglib1.2`, on the download page i have to choose my architecture, but i am not sure where i can find this information. I tried `uname -a` and got `aarch64 GNU/Linux`, is this the architecture?

[image]

If this is my architeture then libglib1.2 is not available for ondroid c2?

Comment: I guess it is `arm`. Can you post the *whole* output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux  3.14.29+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 19 15:57:42 CEST 2016 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: A quick search revealed that it is [`arm64`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/AArch64)

Comment: What exactly did you searched?